# When read lists from text file into pandas dataframe column face ` ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 16 fields in line 3, saw 21 `

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, read-write

I have a text file called `tropical.txt` that have multiple lists that looks like this

```
['papaya', 'mangosteen', 'banana']
[]
['coconut', 'mango']
```

How can I read it into a pandas dataframe such that my final output will look like this? `fruits` is my column name in the expected output.

```
  fruits
0 [apple, orange, banana]
1 []
2 [pineapple, mango]
```

I tried

```
pd.read_csv('tropical.txt')
```

But it's giving me a parse error

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 16 fields in line 3, saw 21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is comma-separated values, so pandas is treating every comma in your list as a column separator. You should try and change the `sep` argument in `pd.read_csv`

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv('tropical.txt', sep="\n")
```

After reading into the pandas dataframe, convert the string into a list.

```
df[0] = df[0].apply(eval)
```